# React won't loop through state in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, async-await

I'm fairly new to React and I have run into a problem. I need to gather data from an API and then use the data to create Polygons with Google Maps. However, I'm experiencing problems accessing it.

When I log this.state.coordinates:

[Console.log result of this.state.coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7fSB.png)

However, when I try to log this.state.coordinates[0] it shows undefined. My guess is that the order in which the data binds is wrong, but I can't seem to find the solution. Here is my code:

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            coordinates: [{}],
            loading: 'initial'
        };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            loading: 'true'
        })
        this.getData()
    }
    
    getData = async () => {
        let coordinates = []
        let res = await axios.get('https://smartcity-parking-api.herokuapp.com/sectors')
        const sectors = await res.data.data
        sectors.map(async (sector, i) => {
            let res = await axios.get(sector.self_links.detail)
            const coordinateArray = await res.data.data.coordinates
            coordinates[i] = {
                latlng: [],
                id: res.data.data.sector_data.sector_id
            }
            coordinateArray.map(coordinate => {
                let latlng = {
                    lat: coordinate.latitude,
                    lng: coordinate.longitude
                }
                coordinates[i].latlng.push(latlng)
            })

            coordinates[i].latlng.push({
                lat: coordinateArray[0].latitude,
                lng: coordinateArray[0].longitude
            })
        })

        this.setState({
        coordinates: coordinates,
        loading: 'false'
    })
    }


render() {

    let { coordinates, loading } = this.state      

    if (loading === 'initial') {
        return <h2>Intializing...</h2>;
    }


    if (loading === 'true') {
        return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
    }


    if (loading === 'false') {
        
        return (
            //Google maps here
        );

    }
```

I have tried making a loader, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Try with a `await Promise.all(sectors.map(...))ˋ. You can also use plain old for-loops if having multiple api calls in parallel is not necessary and you wouldn’t have to use Promise.all

Comment: Hello, I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set coordinates to `null` initially in your constructor and then have your conditional be

`(loading === 'false' && coordinates)`

That may solve your issue.

Comment: Hey Mark, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Change `getData` function to this.**

```
getData = async () => {
    let coordinates = []
    let res = await axios.get('https://smartcity-parking-api.herokuapp.com/sectors')
    const sectors = res.data.data

    const sectorsLinks = await Promise.all(sectors.map(sector => axios.get(sector.self_links.detail)))

    sectorsLinks.map((sector, i) => {
        const coordinateArray = sector.data.data.coordinates;
        coordinates[i] = {
            latlng: [],
            id: sector.data.data.sector_data.sector_id
        }
        coordinateArray.map(coordinate => {
            let latlng = {
                lat: coordinate.latitude,
                lng: coordinate.longitude
            }
            coordinates[i].latlng.push(latlng)
        })

        coordinates[i].latlng.push({
            lat: coordinateArray[0].latitude,
            lng: coordinateArray[0].longitude
        })
    });
    console.log(coordinates);
    this.setState({
        coordinates: coordinates,
        loading: 'false'
    })
};
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your suggestion! This solution works for me!

Comment: I still have less than 15 reputation, so can't upvote yet. Will do so :)